# Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong with NumberFormatter

Tags: swift, numberformatter

I put in this code

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle <-- get error expected declaration
```

Since I thought that I declared formatter in the let I don't understand why I am getting this error.

I am an old school programmer and am fairly new to OOP and Swift.

Comment: And it's `.decimal`, not `.DecimalStyle`.

Comment: You are mixing Swift 2 and 3 APIs in that code.

Comment: @vadian. I don't see how that is a dupe to this one. That other answer certainly doesn't apply here.

Comment: @rmaddy If you put the second line on the top level of a class you'll get that error (**before** the wrong enum case error in Swift 3).

Comment: @vadian Of course. I got focused on the wrong value for the `numberStyle`.